# Wrong domain in chef server password reset

Tags: chef-infra

When I send a password reset email from my chef server, I receive the following email. The domain in the link is incorrect.

> Hello Josh,
>
> Someone has requested a password reset for your Chef user account
>   'jcooley'. If you did not initiate this request, please ignore this
>   email. If you have lost your password, follow this link to reset your
>   password:
>
> https://localhost/password-reset?expires=1540408412&signature=3f77d73716e4a1d8061e6552fbd8d834e4ad21ec9333eb18747bcb315c1272e4&username=jcooley
>
> Thanks,
>
> The Chef Team

How can I correct this domain? I've read that this depends on either the hostname of the server, or (as an override) the *api_fqdn* variable supplied in **/etc/opscode/chef-server.rb**, and that after adding the variable one must simply run `chef-server-ctl reconfigure` for the server to make use of it. My hostname is set, I've added the value to the rb file, and I can see it in the **chef-server-running.json** file, but I still get localhost in my password reset emails.

```
[jcooley@chef ~]$ hostname
chef.example.com
[jcooley@chef ~]$ hostname -f
chef.example.com
[jcooley@chef ~]$ sudo grep fqdn /etc/opscode/chef-server.rb
api_fqdn "chef.example.com"
[jcooley@chef ~]$ sudo jq .private_chef.lb.api_fqdn /etc/opscode/chef-server-running.json
"chef.example.com"
```